# GPIO stopped working suddenly: echo I/O error

Tags: bash, ubuntu, unix, io, gpio

Three months ago, I connected two LEDs to my PC/104 (its OS is Ubuntu 16.04 with kernel 4.19.89) using two GPIO pins: 10 and 17. I wrote some bash code and saved it in a file named `init_gpio_pc104.sh` to switch on the two LEDs:

```
#/bin/bash
echo 10 > /sys/class/gpio/export
echo 17 > /sys/class/gpio/export
echo out > /sys/class/gpio/gpio10/direction
echo out > /sys/class/gpio/gpio17/direction
```

I was executing the bash file using these two commands:

```
sudo modprobe gpio_sch311x
sudo ./init_gpio_pc104.sh
```

Everything worked fine for the past three months (i.e., the LEDs could switch on). Nevertheless, when I executed the same command this morning, this stream of errors appeared in my Ubuntu terminal:

```
sh: echo: I/O error
sh: echo: I/O error
./init_gpio_pc104.sh: 5: ./init_gpio_pc104.sh: cannot create /sys/class/gpio/gpio10/direction:    Directory nonexistent
./init_gpio_pc104.sh: 6: ./init_gpio_pc104.sh: cannot create /sys/class/gpio/gpio17/direction: Directory nonexistent
```

I do not understand why this I/O error appears since I have not updated my Ubuntu or kernel at all. Furthermore, this simple bash code worked very well for three months till now.

I have run `dmesg` and I have obtained the following errors:

> [5.051164] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: port 1 reset error -110
>
> [5.835050] [drm:intel_cpu_fifo_underrun_irq_handler [i915]] *ERROR* > CPU pipe A FIFO underrun
>
> [ 2055.417046] pcan: set_normal_mode(CAN1) failed (err -5)
>
> [2055.417089] pcan: can't open device hardware itself (err -5)!

The file `/var/log/kern.log` contains these GPIO errors:

> Nov 30 18:55:35 echo-desktop kernel: [   83.603083] export_store: invalid GPIO 10
>
> Nov 30 18:55:35 echo-desktop kernel: [   83.603176] export_store: invalid GPIO 17

Comment: Run `dmesg` and check if your kernel didn’t crash. Have you rebooted the machine? Try it, but after checking and maybe saving for further investigation the logs.

Comment: @Oandriy Many thanks. I have run dmesg and I have obtained several errors: 
    [5.051164] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: port 1 reset error -110
    [5.835050] [drm:intel_cpu_fifo_underrun_irq_handler [i915]] ERROR > CPU pipe A FIFO underrun
    [ 2055.417046] pcan: set_normal_mode(CAN1) failed (err -5)
    [2055.417089] pcan: can't open device hardware itself (err -5)!
Furthermore, the file "/var/log.kern.log" also has errors related to the GPIO unit. I have updated my post accordingly

Comment: @Oandriy Actually, when I reboot the machine, the first execution of the code works. Then, after switching off the LEDs , the batch code for switching them on does not work anymore as it gives an I/O error

Comment: @Oandriy I have got a CAN problem as well with two motors that are connected to my PC/104. Maybe this problem is causing my I/O error for the GPIO?

Comment: Sounds like you have electrical issue. When you off leds, current stops going over it. If you have grounding issue it may explain why out of a sudden it stopped working. But from software point of view, have you updated anything else but kernel?

Comment: @Oandriy I see. The only thing that I changed is the PCAN-Linux driver. Since that day, I have started getting I/O issues.  To be more precise, I uninstalled the PCAN-Linux driver (peak-linux-driver-8.11.0) and re-installed it using the realtime-binaries support ("make xeno")